# Oriented stereopair in ERDAS

Tags: lidar, erdas-imagine, stereo-imagery

I am trying to orient a set of intensity LiDAR images in ERDAS Stereoanalyst for
stereo digitizing. The set is consisted of an intensity image and its stereomate.

Stereoanalyst is configured for orienting typical aerial photography which is not the case for me. So I used custom parameters for external orientation (XoYoZo out of the center pixel of the images and omega=phi=kappa=0) as well as custom affine coefficients to move from XY image axis to rows,cols axis (internal orientation), as calculated from image size.

When I try to load my pair to the interface I get an error message about images being of the same geometry. Can't seem to get around it.

Comment: Did you create a stereo model? If so, did you change each frame's interior and exterior inputs? If you don't change those inputs, you get the error "Image pairs are from same geometry!" Is that the exact error you get?

Comment: LIDAR is already 3D, so you don't create a stereo pair from it. Don't you have a point cloud view ? What do you call "stereo mate" in this case ?

Comment: @ Andre Silva: The error message was exactly "Images are of the same geometry". Also Chapter 5 of the User's Guide doesn't provide info on what I am trying to do (I have consulted it before posting the question).

Comment: @ Aggs: No I couldn't create the stereo model , as this error message kept appearing. The images I was using where not typical aerial images, captured by different perspective centers, but LiDAR Intensity images that where created artificially, simulating a typical aerial photography geometry (overlap, parallax etc.). I tried to use Stereo Analyst, in order to create a stereo model for a stereorestitution session.

Comment: @Aggs: As real external orientation data did not exist, I simulated them by calculating absolute positions of center pixels (thus simulating Xo, Yo, Zo) and assuming zero attitudes (omega = phi = kappa =0) since LiDAR Intensity images are actually vertical. Stereo Analyst also requires affine coefficients (for connecting the image coordinate system and the geodetic coordinate system used) which   I calculated using measured points in both images. In theory this should have worked in producing an oriented stereo model, but the error I mentioned kept popping.

Comment: @radouxju: Here you can see the general idea behind it.http://proceedings.spiedigitallibrary.org/proceeding.aspx?articleid=2545484